# Is it true that Brazil made 1 billion dollars from the world cup?

Tags: football, world-cup, finances, fifa

I've heard that Brazil invested 11 billion dollars to prepare for the world cup and have made less than 1 billion. Is it true? If so, does it mean that they lost 10 billion dollars?

And if that's true, didn't they make the calculations to predict the income of their investments?

Comment: Can you provide the reference from where you know this? It might help to give an answer.

Comment: @SahuKahn I heard it on the news, can't find any online link that support or deny that claim, if anything pops up, I'll edit the question and notify you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time researching and this is as good as information I could find, though there seems like there is no released official earned revenue just yet.

Based on this http://www.tsmplug.com/football/world-cup-total-revenue-4-billion/ Brazil was projected to make $4 Billion through marketing and TV rights.

And based on this document released by FIFA itself http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/02/36/32/63/faq_en_neutral.pdf, it costed $15 Billion for Brazil to host the world cup ($2 Billion of that which was covered byFIFA).

So that means that Brazil ended up loosing $11 Billion!

Comment: so there’s some truth to it!